# produce certain string in Array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

halo, first of all i am sorry if this an easy question, but right now i am stuck to figure it out the mistake i am having. (i am just learning JavaScript BTW). So i have a function that will an produce an array of string, if the length of array is odd, the very middle of an array will contain asterisk, and the rest will just empty string. But if the length of array is even, the index of mid and before mid will contain asterisk (*). The test case will be like this:

```
console.log (Exercise(5) // ['','','*','','']    
console.log (Exercise(4) // ['','*','*','']
console.log( Exercise1(0)) // invalid input
```

i figure it out that first you have to make an array to contain the string and then divide the length of array with 2 so that we can know weather the array is odd or even. If odd, i will push the asterisk to index array [mid] and if it even i will push an asterisk to index array [mid-1] and [mid]. This is what i got so far :

```
function Exercise1(num){
var result = [] ;
var midArr = num.length/2 
var oddArr = Math.floor (midArr)
for (var i = 0; i<num.length; i++){
   if (num.length % 2 !== 0) {
      result = push.result(num[oddArr]('*'))
      return result
    } else if (num.length % 2 === 0 ){
      result = push.result(num[midArr-1][mid]('*'));
      return result
    } else {
      return invalid  ;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is it my logic or my syntax is incorrect or i am just plain stupid.

Comment: First of all, you are using `num` as an array (accessing `length` and similar) but it's the parameter and from what i can see should be a number.

Comment: i dont understand :(

Comment: @nomad use `var midArr = num/2` instead of `var midArr = num.length/2` as num is a number, not an array

Comment: can you suggest what i have to fix with my code ?

Comment: @maljukan ohh i see, so that we can get wheater its odd or even right ?

Answer (score 0):

An easier method might be to create an array of blank strings half the length of the array and then use spread:

```js
function Exercise(length) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(length) || length < 1) return null;
  const blanks = Array(Math.floor((length - 1) / 2)).fill('');
  return length % 2 === 0
    ? [...blanks, '*', '*', ...blanks]
    : [...blanks, '*', ...blanks];
}

console.log(Exercise(5));
console.log(Exercise(4));
console.log(Exercise(0));
```

Comment: ohh, so you asign empty string to variabel/const. I didn't think of that

Comment: but i didnt quite understand the syntax : if (!Number.isInteger(length) || length < 1) return null;
  const blanks = Array(Math.floor((length - 1) / 2)).fill('');
  return length % 2 === 0   can you elaborate more ?

Comment: The first line returns null if the input isn't in the desired format. The second line creates an array of blank strings half the length, or half of the length minus one (whichever produces a whole number. Then, just spread it into the returned array.

Comment: and whats up with the question mark before the array ? is it the requirement to spread an array ?

Comment: That's the ternary operator. Condition is true, return the first expression, else return the second expression.

Comment: this is the first time i hear ternary operation.. thank you so much btw, you guys answer  is most helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loops combined with +/- indexes to make your life much easier here.

Though it's worth mentioning that if your number is 1 or 2, the result will be [*] or [*,*], respectively. Wasn't sure how you wanted to handle that.

```js
var Exercise1 = (num) => {
  let arr = [];
  if (num % 2) {
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){arr.push((i==~~(num/2))?'*':'');}
  } else {
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){arr.push((i==(num/2)-1 || i==(num/2))?'*':'');}
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log('Even (4): ['+Exercise1(4)+']');
console.log('Odd (5): ['+Exercise1(5)+']');
```